# How to prevent a lot of if/else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How to prevent a lot of if/else statements in a function to determine a value?

This question must have been asked before but I can not seem to find a good answer on React specifically after React Hooks have been introduced.

```
const { yearFilters, rcpFilters } = useSearch();

  const determineValue = () => {
    let finalArray = '';
    if (yearFilters === 'end' && rcpFilters === 'high') {
      return (finalArray = 'value1');
    } else if (yearFilters === 'intermediate' && rcpFilters === 'high') {
      return (finalArray = 'value2');
    } else if (yearFilters === 'begin' && rcpFilters === 'high') {
      return (finalArray = 'value3');
    } else if (yearFilters === 'end' && rcpFilters === 'medium') {
      return (finalArray = 'value4');
    } else if (yearFilters === 'intermediate' && rcpFilters === 'medium') {
      return (finalArray = 'value5');
    } else if (yearFilters === 'begin' && rcpFilters === 'medium') {
      return (finalArray = 'value6');
    } else return (finalArray = 'value7');
  };

  const value = determineValue();
```

So as you see I am pulling two Hooks out of useSearch(), and depending on those the value should change.  Is there a better way than doing it like this? Is a switch/case situation possible here?

Comment: `return (finalArray = 'value1');` is useless - no need to return an assignment. Just do `return 'value1';`

Comment: This is basically a logic/algorithm question. Maybe it's relevant to Javascript, but hardly to React and/or Hooks.

Comment: If the result cannot be derived from the input computationally then you have to list the combinations somehow anyway. If you want this to be more "declarative" you could store the result in a nested object, keyed by the input. E.g. `{end: {high: 'value1', medium: 'value4'}, ...}`. Or maybe a `switch` statement would make the logic easier to read.

Comment: You could  start with `let finalArray = 'value7'; if (yearFilters === 'end' && rcpFilters === 'high') { finalArray = 'value1'; else if ...; } return finalArray;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's no need for that `finalArray` local variable, which just clutters things up.

I'd test `yearFilters` against its possible values just once, and within each of those test `rcpFilters`, probably with lookup objects or `Map`s:

```
// Outside the component (no need to recreate it)
const yearFilterValues = {
    begin: {
        high: "value2",
        medium: "value6",
    },
    intermediate: {
        high: "value2",
        medium: "value5",
    },
    end: {
        high: "value1",
        medium: "value4",
    }
};

// In the component:
const { yearFilters, rcpFilters } = useSearch();
const determineValue = () => {
    const rcpValues = yearFilterValues[yearFilters];
    return rcpValues.?[rcpFilters] ?? "value7";
    // Or if you can't use optional chaining and nullish coalescing:
    // return (rcpValues && rcpValues[rcpFilters] && rcpValues[rcpFilters]) || "value7";
};

const value = determineValue();
```

*(Note that the version for when you can't use optional chaining and nullish coalescing relies on the fact that none of the target values is falsy, they're all strings with at least one character.)*

Comment: What would you do if the value1-6 were dynamic, and I had to use them at different places? (they aren't value1-value6 all the time)

Comment: @BridlerShoc - Probably nested `switch` or nested `if`/`else if`/`else` (which, in JavaScript, are basically the same thing, even more so than other similar languages) or perhaps using a structure like the above but where the "values" are functions that you then call to get the dynamic result.

Comment: Thanks for replying in a constructive answer instead of criticizing my question such as others! A blessing for beginners. :)

Answer (score 0):

if your finalArray is static, you can put you logic into a separate array object. like this

```js
export const obj = [
  { finalArray: 'value1', yearFilters: 'end', rcpFilters: 'high' },
  { finalArray: 'value2', yearFilters: 'intermediate', rcpFilters: 'high' },
  ...
]


let finalArray = obj.find((item) => {
  return item.yearFilters === 'end' && item.rcpFilters === 'high'
}).finalArray
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a React related problem, just programming fundamentals.

A switch statement is not perfect but for your case works well. It is more readable.

You can use this solution if the combination of conditionals is n:2 (your case is 3:2, 3 options with 2 combinations)

If you have more than 2 combinations for each case I don't recommend a switch statement and use other methods like object literals: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals

```js
const { yearFilters, rcpFilters } = useSearch();

  const determineValue = () => {
    let finalArray = '';
    
    switch(yearFilters){
      case "end":
        rcpFilters === "high" ? finalArray="value1": finalArray="value4";
      break;
      
      case "intermediate":
       rcpFilters === "high" ? finalArray="value2": finalArray="value5";
      break;
       
      case "begin":
       rcpFilters === "high" ? finalArray="value3": finalArray="value6";
      break;
      
      default:
      finalArray="value7";
      break;
    }
    
    return finalArray;
  };

  const value = determineValue();
```